# R Shiny 500 Internal Server Error after I run the app once

Tags: r, shiny

I've been using R shiny for some time now, but all of a sudden, I'm facing this really odd problem. If I restart my PC and launch my R Shiny app on my local PC (Windows + Chrome), it works fine, and I can test locally (http://127.0.0.1:5117/) my app.
Then, I stop it and launch it again. From this point on, Chrome keeps giving me this error message:
"500 Internal Server Error".
It cannot be a code bug since it worked the first time I launched it. I try the same exact steps with different shiny apps I have on my end, and they all cause the same problem.
I can share here one of the sample shiny app I have, but I don't think it would help much, since again, it works the first time, and then it keeps giving me "500 Internal Server Error".

Since my app was really big, I started to remove pieces of code, step by step. What is really weird is that I basically removed everything and I still get that error! This is how the code looks like right now. I have one file called app.R and a second file in the same folder called global.R. This is the app.R file.

```
#this is app.R
source("global.R")  

ui <- dashboardPage(  
  title = "Custom Dashboard", 
  dashboardHeader(title = "AB MuniGate"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(  
    #includeCSS("www/styles.css"),
    
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Contact", tabName = "contact", icon = icon("envelope"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody( 
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem(tabName = "contact",
        h2("Contact.")
          )
    )
  )
)
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {    
  cat("\nHello\n")
}

cat("\nLaunching   'shinyApp' ....")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is instead the global.R file:

```
library(shiny)
cat("\n* trying to use library shinyjs ")

#library(shinyBS)
library(shinydashboard)
#library(shinyjs)
cat("\n* library shinyjs  succesfull!")

cat("\n\n\n ******** 'global.R'   completed. ***********************  Curr.Time: ",format(Sys.time()),"\n\n\n")
```

I also attach a screenshot of what Chrome shows me. Please let me know if there's anything else I could share. Thanks
[image]

Comment: I presume you have a `shiny-server` where you deploy it after testing locally. Have a look at the log file, most likely there is a bug in the code, could also be a dependency issues such as package

Comment: @Pork Chop The log doesn't show any error, just a couple of warnings like "Warning in sink() : no sink to remove". Also, if there was a bug in the code, then it wouldn't even run the first time, right?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody will face a similar problem, I managed to fixed mine by coping and pasting all the files (excluding the R project file) into a new folder and creating a new project with a new one.
For some odd reasons, the issue was hidden in the R project file that apparently got corrupted.
I checked its settings but nothing seemed to explain this odd behaviour.
Moving the files to a new folder and using a new R project with new name fixed my problem.